# How To Enter Console App Commands From A Batch File

Tags: batch-file, testing

I am currently developing a C++ program that processes nodes in a binary tree. The project is a console app that takes in commands from cin.

I want to be able to run tests with a script, so I am using a batch file to input a number of commands.

a small snippet of C++ Code

```
else if (command == "insert")
    {
        cin >> parameter;
        cout << "insert found: " << parameter << "\n";
        bst::insert(parameter, tree);
    }
```

the batch file (as it is currently written)

```
@echo off
cd "Path\Foobar"
app.exe "insert word"
```

will only open the application, it won't send in the commands to the application. The command given should tell the app to insert a node with the key "word" into the tree. If the application were to receive an incorrect command, it would flag it with a response. But the app just sits there and waits for commands (manual commands work just fine to).

I've seen numerous documents on writing batch files as well as other questions here, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around why the application will not accept my commands.

I am currently running on windows 10 and using visual studio 2015.

Comment: This is not a batch file problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do  `echo "insert word" | app.exe`. That should fix your problem, but you should look up taking command-line arguments in c++, that would be a more proper fix.

Comment: This is certainly a step in the right direction, my app now reads the command...on an infinite loop. I presume this has to due with the app reading in commands on a for loop. I am somewhat familiar with console apps with formal parameters, but I'm not sure if a set up like this will be appropriate for the project. I was told the code would undergo testing with a script, so I don't think I want the app to require formal parameters. The syntax used in the example is what is required by the project.